# Problema al extraer urls de imagenes "src" con cheerio y puppeteer

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs

Estoy tratando de extraer las urls "src" de unas imágenes de una web con *headless browser*, *cheerio* y *puppeteer*  y solo consigo extraer las primeras urls de las imágenes y el resto salen *undefined*, ¿alguna idea?

Este es mi código

```
var items=[];

(async () => {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
 
    await page.goto('https://www.milanuncios.com/anuncios/bmw.htm?fromSearch=1&fromSuggester=1');
    await page.waitForSelector('#cuerpo .aditem-detail-image-container', { timeout: 1000 });

    const body = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelector('body').innerHTML;
    });
   var $ = cheerio.load(body);
 //  console.log('todo', body);
   const pageItems = $('#cuerpo .aditem-detail-image-container').toArray()
         //const pageItems = $('.card js-masonry-item card-product product tracked').toArray()
                .map(item => {
                    const $item = $(item);
                  //  console.log('todo', $item);
                    return {
                      //  id: $item.attr('data-adid'),
                       title: $item.find('.aditem-detail-title').text(),
                       link: $item.find('a').attr('href'),
                       image:  $item.find('img').attr('src'),
                       price: $item.find('.aditem-price').text(),
                    
                    };
                });
                 const allItems = items.concat(pageItems);
            console.log(pageItems.length,'items retrieved', allItems.length, 'acumulated');
    //  console.log(pageItems);
      fs.writeFile('./items.json', JSON.stringify(allItems), 'utf8', function(error) {
            if (error) return console.log('error', error);
            console.log(allItems.length, 'items saved');
        }); 
       process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(allItems));

    await browser.close();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Por que las imágenes se cargan dinámicamente a media que se hace `scroll`. te recomiendo revisar [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529332/puppeteer-scroll-down-until-you-cant-anymore)

Comment: Ya funciona con esa sugerencia , muchas gracias

Comment: Sería muy útil para la comunidad si pudieras responder a tu pregunta incluyendo el código con el pudiste solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Añadimos la funcion autoScroll

```
async function autoScroll(page){
        await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var distance = 100;
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;

                if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                                              }
                                  }, 100);
                          });
               });
        }
```

y luego la llamamos despues de waitForSelector

```
await autoScroll(page);
```